# Linting react typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript-eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am trying to lint my react project with typescript template. I want to use the airbnb style guide, but when the ran the comm `npx eslint --init` I only get the standard option and the xo option. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [ESLint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/getting-started), assuming you have a `package.json` file, you can install and configure ESLint with:

```bash
npm init @eslint/config
```

Then, in the configuration, you should select `To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style` option as an answer to `How would you like to use ESLint?`. For the styling question, you can choose `Use a popular style guide` and `Airbnb` options, respectively.

Note: I also tried with `npx eslint --init` command, and see the `Airbnb` option.

Comment: But that is the problem am facing right now. The Airbnb option as well as the google option does not appear

Comment: What is your Node.js version? Can you check it with `node -v` command? [ESLint requires ^12.22.0, ^14.17.0, or >=16.0.0](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/getting-started)

Comment: my node version is 16.17.0
and actually, I noticed when I ran the command `npx create-react-app`, I do not get the style guide from airbnb and google but I tried setting it up without the command `npx create-react-app` and I got all the options

Comment: `create-react-app` comes with predefined ESLint configuration. Can you check `package.json` and `.eslintrc` files? If there is a field for ESLint, you can remove it and retry.

Comment: I ran the command and have no eslint installed globally. Even tried switching to root dir and nothing there. This is a very confusing error lol. Thanks for helping me out still

Comment: I removed the eslint configuration from `package.json` and tried the init. still did not get it. `create-react-app` does not come with `.eslintrc`. The funny though is, I had a different project I worked with that  I had that option but for whatever reason I am not getting it this time around

Comment: Interesting. Do you have eslint packages in your package.json since `create-react-app` has predefined rules? Maybe, you can remove the eslint related packages from package.json with `npm uninstall` and try again. That's all I can think of